# What are appropriate learning algorithms to use on complex waveform data?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, fourier-transform

I anticipate acquiring a rather large data set, consisting of several data streams of complex waveform data generated by a single complex process, simultaneously measured at different locations, and a stream of measurements of an index of the quality of output from that process measured over the same period but at a much lower frequency. "Complex" here means complicated, not simple, rather than referring to a stream of complex numbers.

I intend to use the waveform data as the input to a supervised learning algorithm for nowcasting the index. Previous work in this area has concentrated on spectral power – the volume in each waveform of variation in specified frequency ranges.

I face two problems on which I seek advice. The first and smaller problem is that I have never worked with waveform data and do not know the common or standard learning algorithms used in this area. I know how to use the fast former transform to flip the time to the frequency domain, which lets me replicate the earlier work, but that is about it.

The second and larger problem is that the earlier work in the field has not achieved a satisfactory level accuracy in the sort of contemporaneous "prediction" I seek to do, and I have no faith that spectral power is the best, or even a good, summary of the data for this purpose. Perhaps instead I should be looking at correlation or anticoagulation between waveforms from different locations. Or maybe the presence or absence of occasional spikes would affect the outcome, positively or negatively. Or perhaps only one of the locations is actually useful.

I will not belabor the point further, except to say I would like to use an algorithm that is agnostic between these possibilities, and capable of finding the patterns that are there, rather than being limitted to the patterns I pre-specify, by data transformation or otherwise.

My statistical background is in econometrics, which is to say mainly applied regression, so this is new territory for me. It is time series data, I suppose, but not the kind of time series with which I am familiar

Comment: What kind of data is this? Knowing that may help understdangint the relevance of methods